# C++ const casting

Tags: c++, casting, constants

I am trying to print the value of a const but it is not working. I am making a return to C++ after years so I know casting is a possible solution but I can't get that working either.

The code is as follows:

```
  //the number of blanks surrounding the greeting
    const int pad = 0;

    //the number of rows and columns to write
    const int rows = pad * 2 + 3;
    const string::size_type cols    =       greeting.size() + pad * 2 + 2;

    cout << endl << "Rows : " + rows;
```

I am trying to print the value of 'rows' without success.

Comment: sisko, can one of the answers below be accepted on this old question? It is not mandatory to accept, but it may be helpful for future readers to see which worked (if you can remember, of course!).

Answer (score 6):

You want:

```
cout << endl << "Rows : " << rows;
```

Note this has nothing to do with `const` - C++ does not allow you to concatenate strings and numbers with the `+` operator. What you were actually doing was that mysterious thing called pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Not exactly: as it has been pointed out to me below, `"Rows :"` is a `char*` and when `char*`s are printed out, they're printed out starting at the position they point at until they hit a null character.

Comment: @trutheality Nope, what I'm saying is correct. s[rows] where s is a char * and rows is an integer evaluates to a char, not  a char *.

Comment: @trutheality You are quite right. I don't know where I was going there - blame it on the anti-depressants.

Comment: @trutheality that example exits without flushing output

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there:

```
cout << endl << "Rows : " << rows;
```

The error is because `"Rows : "` is a string literal, thus is a constant, and generally speaking is not modified as you may think.

Going slightly further, you likely used `+` (colloquially used as a concatenation operation) assuming you needed to build a string to give to the output stream. Instead `operator <<` returns the output stream when it is done, allowing chaining.

```
// It is almost as if you did:
(((cout << endl) << "Rows : ") << rows)
```

Comment: Um, not so. It can never be modified, and the OP's code is not attempting to do so.

Comment: @Neil: Was trying to avoid the pointer talk, as he was using `+` to mean concatenation. But +1 went your way for the pointer arithmetic acknowledgement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
std::cout << std::endl << "Rows : " << rows << std::endl;
```

I make this mistake all the time as I also work with java a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need

```
std::cout << std::endl << "Rows : " << rows << std::endl;
```

The reason (or one of the reasons) is that `"Rows : "` is a `char*` and the `+` operator for `char*`s doesn't concatenate strings, like the one for `std::string` and strings in languages like Java and Python.

Comment: Or strings (`std::string`, that is) in C++. `char*` and `std::string` are different types. `char*` is a carryover from C, `std::string` is new with C++.

Comment: Actually, in this case, there is a `operator+` available. `"Rows : "` will devolve into a `const char*`, which can have an int added to it, i.e. `"Rows : " + 3`. The resulting output is that only `"s : "` is written.